# Respond from the correct email

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I forward my work email to my Gmail and I want to respond automatically without having to select my work email from there.

How automatically to respond from the email where I received mail from automatically?

Comment: This explains how to make Gmail automatically select the correct From address when replying (just adding some more keyphrases for Google, since this was rather hard to find).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try the `Reply from the same address the message was sent to` option in you GMail settings?

Go to `Gmail settings > Accounts and Import`. Under `When receiving a message:` select `Reply from the same address the message was sent to`.

The works for me when I fetch the mail from IMAP or POP, but I haven't tested with forwarding. So it may not work.

Good Luck

Comment: I did the same as Tony suggested and it has worked fine for me.

Comment: Tony's answer is head on, and works. I would however just like that it does indeed work with forwarding as well - as long as you can send with that mail-account as well.

Comment: Tony's Answer. But remember to do add an additional From: address as well, as explained [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370). I suppose this is what Gnub means.